# Upgrade to last ember-cli on Linux

Tags: linux, ember-cli

The last version to date is 2.3 and the 1.13.15 is installed on my machine. How do I nice-update to 2.3? Unistall the current first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each set of Ember CLI Releases comes complete with upgrade instructions:

[Releases - ember-cli/ember-cli](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases)

If you're looking to upgrade both Ember CLI, Ember, AND Ember Data I'd suggest upgrading to each minor revision starting at 2.0, fix all of the deprecation warnings, and then proceed to the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I want to update the whole thing. I currently don't have any project running 'cause I'm just beggining to learn, so, can I upgrade to 2.3 directly?

Comment: @Gjaa - If you haven't started a project yet, you can just upgrade Ember CLI and then start the new Ember project.

Comment: Got three deprecation warnings. first one is: "update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible." how do I do that?